# Apache virtual host redirect to root - ubuntu 20 WSL2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm new in apache2, I have windows 10 WSL2 Ubuntu 20, and trying to set my local virtual host, but, It only works in http://localhost and not in http://artek.test (my vhost local)

I created a folder(artek) and file (index.html) in:

```
/var/www/artek/index.html
```

which is:

```
<html>
<title>Artek</title>
<body>
<h1>Artek<h2>
descriptions...
</body>
</html>
```

and I created my conf file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/artek.test.conf
```

inside:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@artek.test
    ServerName artek.test
    ServerAlias artek.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/artek
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/artek-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/artek-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

after that:

```
sudo a2ensite artek.test.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
service apache2 reload
```

but when I go to http://artek.test it shows this error:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

and when I go to http://localhost it shows my page!

[my page in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWWfY.png)

why?, what's wrong with this??

I hope you could help me.

Greetings

---

Hi again,
even i've just edited /etc/hosts like this:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       PE-LPALQ2156.localdomain        PE-LPALQ2156
127.0.0.1       artek.test

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

but nothing happen, the same DNS error :(

Comment: That's a DNS error. Do you have a DNS node set up for artek.test? Or, if you're just testing locally at this point, do you have a hosts file entry for it?

Comment: Hi Don, DNS node?, i dont know exactly about this. Ive just edited my etc/hosts like my post but i have the same error.

Comment: I'd expect that to work. Maybe your browser has a local cache that needs clearing? Or try a different browser that hasn't been used for this yet?